# Flutter converting variable to Lat & Lng

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, double, var

i have function which gets user phone location, and i want to set Marker on this location.

**The question is :**

How i can type to `LatLng()` location of user's phone.

**What i tried? :**

When i type there var *locationMessage* there is an error:

*2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found*

```
  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    var lastPosition = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();

    print(lastPosition);

    setState(() {
      locationMessage = "${position.altitude}, ${position.longitude}";
    });
  }
```

```
GoogleMap(
            markers: _markers,
            initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _controller.complete(controller);
              setState(() {
                _markers.add(Marker(
                    icon: mapMarker,
                    markerId: const MarkerId("marker-1"),
                    position: LatLng(//HOW TO INSERT HERE USER'S LOCATION)));
              });
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `locationMessage` with `String` type use `Position` type.

so instead of

```
 var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

replace with

```
locationMessage = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

Then here

```
........
........
........
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
      icon: mapMarker,
      markerId: const MarkerId("marker-1"),
      position: LatLng(locationMessage.latitude, locationMessage. longitude)));///PASS LAT AND LONG
    });
........
........
........
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like this:

1. create `_currentLocation` var:

   `LatLng _currentLocation;`
2. update value inside getCurrentLocation() / setState():

   `_currentLocation = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);`
3. inside `_markers.add` use:

   `position: _currentLocation`
4. You should initialize `_currentLocation` value inside initState() by calling getCurrentLocation():

```
      @override
      void initState() {
        getCurrentLocation();
        super.initState();
      }
```

---

Note: if you are using `google_maps_flutter` package and you want to show the user position, you can set the [myLocationEnabled](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/myLocationEnabled.html) property to `true`:

```
GoogleMap(
   myLocationEnabled: true,
   ...
```

Comment: Okay thanks but how to initialize _currentLocation value inside initState() by calling getCurrentLocation()?

Comment: @Malak I've edited the answer to include initState()

Comment: but then ```Non-nullable instance field '_currentLocation' must be initialized```.  When when i add ```late``` it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know why but it isn't reading value from this function
```void getCurrentLocation() async {
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    var lastPosition = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();

    print(lastPosition);

    setState(() {
      LatLng _currentLocation = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can try creating with some value, that will be updated on initState(): `LatLng _currentLocation = LatLng(0,0);`

Comment: Unfortunately it accept 0,0 values, this initState() should be in Class or inside getCurrentLocation() function?

Comment: Now it is in class.

Comment: If you need more generic guidance, you can check some tutorials like: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-geolocator-plugin ,
https://blog.logrocket.com/geolocation-geocoding-flutter/